# Get the Year ago data using SQL

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a table that should display the price of a product for current year and the previous year. I have to implement this solution in snowflake. I have a table like shown below.

| product_id | product_price | Fiscal_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | $100 | 202002 |
| x1 | $200 | 201902 |
| x1 | $300 | 201802 |

I have a separate date dimension table which have previous fiscal week year are mapped and looks like below.

| Fiscal_year | PREV_FISCAL_YEAR |
| --- | --- |
| 202002 | 201902 |
| 201902 | 201802 |
| 201802 | 201702 |

Now I want to create a table in a such a manner that it should display the price of the product `x1` for current fiscal year and the price of product in previous fiscal year.

**Expected Table output**

| product_id | product_price | Fiscal_Year | prev_product_price | prev_Fiscal_Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | $100 | 202002 | $200 | 201902 |
| x1 | $200 | 201902 | $300 | 201802 |
| x1 | $300 | 201802 | somevalue | somevalue |

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use LAG() function.

Comment: product id and fiscal year are not unique values. There can be duplicates so if I use lag() then I might end up putting the same fiscal year value to duplicate records

Comment: *product id and fiscal year are not unique values.* And `(product_id, Fiscal_year)` values pair is not unique too? if so then the task is unsolvable.

Comment: yeah even pair is not unique

Comment: You tell that `201902` is previous fiscal year for `202002`. If there exists 2 different rows with `201902` and different `product_price` values (for example, $100 and $110) then what value must be used as `prev_product_price` for `202002`?

Comment: I believe we will have to aggregate the data for fiscal year for a product id. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: *we will have to aggregate the data for fiscal year for a product id.* This **must** produce unique `(product_id, Fiscal_year)`... if it is performed correctly, of course.

Comment: You can try as follows. 1) Get the Product price for each product , per year. 2) You analytical function ROW_NUMBER() to pick up only one row per product per year 3) Use the lag function to get the price of the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your table and joins:

```
select tf.*, tp.*
from t tf join
     date_dimension dd
     on tf.fiscal_year = dd.fiscal_year left join
     t tp 
     on tp.fiscal_year = dd.prev_fiscal_year and
        tp.product_id = tf.product_id;
```

However, if you have one row per fiscal year and product, you could just use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(price) over (partition by product_id order by fiscal_year) as prev_price
from t;
```

Comment: here in this line dd.product_id,  date dimension won't having any product id